# How do I update minimum required quantity for configurable products for specific attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, manage-stock

Magento: 1.9.2.0

I have a configurable product [listed](https://www.styroshop.com/products/styro-sheet-panels-and-boards) in magento store. This configurable product has more than 200 simple products(sizes) associated with it. The attributes are Length X Width X Thickness (cm). I have 9 sizes for thickness 5 each for lengths and widths.

Now I want to limit the `minimum_cart_qty=5 for thickness<=2.5cm.`

In other words whenever a customer chooses a thickness 2.5, 2, 1.5 or 1cm The system should not allow them to add products to cart.

Actually these are 4x5x5 = 100 simple products that need to be updated.

Problem here is bulk updating minimum cart quantity, I don't want to update via product stocks because that messes my images.
I believe it is possible by Magmi but I don't know how to use Magmi.

How do I achieve this?

Problem with bulk attribute edit is that how do I know which products to select as the product names and SKU's are not based upon sizes.

Comment: How is bulk editing the minimum cart quantity messaging up your images? What data is in the CSV you are using? Using the import/export profiles and having a csv with SKU and Min Qty Allowed in Cart would work.

Comment: The csv upload of product stocks does work, and when product page loads the image loads fine, but when I choose a size variation the images doesn't show or goes blank.

Comment: Again, what data are you including in the CSV?

Comment: All the data, it includes all fields.

Comment: Have you tried just the SKU and min qty amount using the "Dataflow - Profiles" method instead?

Comment: I haven't yet, I will try that and let you know. 
One more question the listing that I already messed up on my staging, how do I get the original listing from my Live website to Staging. Which file(s) to copy? Can I just export only that product from Live and upload to Staging or there is anything else to it? Kindly advise which export/import method to use?